# Error with a jQuery plugin after an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/css/metro-bootstrap.css">

 <script  src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/min/metro.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/js/metro-dropdown.js"></script>

<Script type="text/javascript">

function getContent() {

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        traditional : true,
        url : "content.htm",

        success : function(response) {

            $('#someDiv').append(response);

        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });

}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="someDiv">


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

When I get the code from the server (its a java server with spring3mvc). and I put it in the html, the metro-ui visual framework doesn't work because the new html code is in the DOM after the DOM was created.

I need to reload the plugin of metro-ui. I think if I do that , the new code will work.

Any suggestions? thanks

new info

the library im using is metro.ui here is the link
http://metroui.org.ua/ .

here is the header

```
<!-- Metro-UI-CSS-master -->
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/css/metro-bootstrap.css">

<script  src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/min/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/js/metro-dropdown.js"></script>


<!--  calendar -->
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/js/metro/metro-calendar.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/js/metro/metro-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- fin calendar -->
<!--  fin Metro-UI-CSS-master -->
<!--  calendar -->
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/js/metro/metro-calendar.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/js/metro/metro-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- fin calendar -->
```

and this i an example of a component thats works if i include it in the page without ajax, and if a get it from an ajax function it doesent work. its a file upload button in a text field.

```
<div data-role="input-control" class="input-control file info-state">
<input type="file" style="z-index: 0;" tabindex="-1"><input type="text" style="z-index: 1; cursor: default;" readonly="" id="__input_file_wrapper__">
                                    <button class="btn-file" type="button"></button>
                                </div>
```

and here is an example in the web of the author of the library
http://metroui.org.ua/forms.html
seek "Select, file, textarea" in the page, is the file upload example, it have a little folder when you click it you can select a file etc...

Comment: Are you applying the right classes to your elements? in this case what ever is in your response. the plugin is supposed to work out of the box with the right classes applied to the div

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for said plugin?

Comment: http://metroui.org.ua/ . this is the link to de library , the classes and element are right, i know that because i try it whitout ajax and it works fine. its like the library use $('#someID').onclick(...)...   and thats only work the first time i include de jquery library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `.append` you need to re-initialize your metro components so they can update your UI.  However, it's not very clear in the doc how to do this, but I came across this [github issue](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/issues/138) which seems to explain a similar issue.  Based on that issue I would try something like this.

```
$('#someDiv').append(response).dropdown().init();
```

Or maybe, leave out the init() and just try

```
$('#someDiv').append(response).dropdown();
```

Comment: it works! (i feel apache), thanks thats works fine, i need only to find the functions and it will work fine, thanks !

Comment: For the appbar it's very similar.
    $('.app-bar')).appbar().resize();

Answer (score 0):

Try using html instead of append, like this...

```
$('#someDiv').html(response);
```

Comment: That really should make no difference as far as whether or not the plugin gets applied to the elements.

Comment: i try it , but its the same problem, all elements in the load of the page works but when i add a new element whit ajax like a button or  something that uses jquery , this new element doesent work

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you question, it's clear now so I'll try again.